# Jquery- Abrir modal para elimintar item

Tags: php, html, jquery, html5, jquery-ui

Mediante jquery genero un listado de elementos "li" de forma dinámica, tengo dos listas y mediante drag and drop creo estas listas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El **código resultante** de un item seria este

```
    <div class="content">
    <ol class="ui-sortable">
        <li class="action-element ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle newClass" data-id="txtType">
            <div data-id="1" class="boxElementText"><div style="float: right">
                <i class="fas fa-trash btnDeleteItem" data-type="btnImgText" style=""></i>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span class="titleField" "="">Campo de Texto</span><br>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Titulo..." class="title"><br> 
                <input type="text" placeholder="Descripcion..." class="input-value"><br>
                <input type="checkbox" class="chbRequired">
            </div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Por cada item quiero vincular el botón "btnDeleteItem" con un formulario modal de boostrap, eso lo hago de esta manera

```
    $(document).on('click', '.btnDeleteItem', function(event) {
        jQuery.noConflict();
        $('#deleteModal').modal('toggle');
    });
```

Esto me genera por pantalla un modal como este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema lo tengo para capturar el botón "SI" que es la confirmación que quiero borrar el elemento.

Antes de hacerlo con el modal, como tenia el foco en la lista "ul" lo hacia de esta manera

```
        $(document).on('click', '.btnDeleteItem', function(event) {
        if (window.confirm('Deseas borrar este elemento ？')) {
            let $li = $(event.currentTarget).closest("li");
            $li.remove();
        }
    });
```

Pero ahora al abrir primero el modal, no se si desde el botón debo pasarle algun identificador al formulario, para que cuando haga click en el botón de "confirmar" pueda encontrar el item.

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, deberás pasarle algún identificador para que sepa que item borrar.

Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera (voy a suponer que el identificador con el que trabajas es el id):

- En el icono de la papelera, añade un data-id con el id del elemento.
- Al hacer click sobre el icono de la papelera, añade ese data-id como un atributo data en la ventana modal.

> ```
> $('.ventana-modal').attr('data-id',id);
> ```

- Si el usuario confirma el borrado, captura el data-id de la modal:

> ```
> var id = $('.ventana-modal').attr('data-id');
> ```

- Y en cualquiera de los casos (confirmación o cancelación), borra al final el data-id que has añadido en la ventana modal:

> ```
> $('.ventana-modal').removeAttr('data-id');
> ```

Comment: gracias @cooper ya lo he solucionado , ahora publico la solución . 1000 gracias

Answer (score 0):

Al final la solución ha sido esta, gracias a los comentarios de @cooper

**Botón que lanza el modal**

```
    $(document).on('click', '.btnDeleteItem', function(event) {
        jQuery.noConflict();
        var id = ($(this).attr('data-id'));
        $('#deleteModal').attr('data-id',id);
        $('#deleteModal').modal('toggle');
    });
```

**Una vez se abre el modal, en el botón de "borrar" hago lo siguiente**

```
    $(document).on('click', '.btnModalDeleteItem', function(event) {

        var id = $('#deleteModal').attr('data-id');

        var div =  $('.element').filter(function(){
            return $(this).attr('data-id') == id;
        });

        div.closest('.action-element').remove();

        $('#deleteModal').modal('hide');
    });
```